# Developing Word add-ins for Macintosh

Tags: macos, ms-word, ms-office

I have an add-in for Word 2007 developed using VS2008/.NET 3.5.
What do I need to do in order for Mac users to use this add-in with their Word 2008? (or did MS make sure it would be impossible to do...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mac version of Word is a totally different beast internally.  AFAIK, the only documented "plugin" API for Word on the Mac is its [AppleScript interface](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/developers/default.mspx).  It *might* be useful for what you want to do but you'd probably be close to starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Its not standard/possible. The .NET Framework is not available on Mac.

Comment: Yes, but the Mono libraries do not have anything like this as far as I know.